# Can't read iomega Ego external Hard Drive Drive - detected in Disk Management, but assigning a drive letter is grayed out

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have a problem with my iOmega Ego external Hard Drive. I can connect it to my laptop (Windows 8 & 7 & Mac have been tried out) and it is always shown in Disk Utlity/Disk Management (see picture below). The drive is turning, I can feel it when I touch it, and the little LED on it is also on & white (not red, which would indicate it being broken somehow).

However, I can not access it. I read that I could try changing the Drive Letter, but that option is grayed out. So, what else can I do, except format it and lose all my data?

I read in these forums that connecting it to a computer that runs Linux might be an option... But I don't know anybody who has Linux, so alternatives would be very welcome, thanks.

[image: Thanks a million!!]

Comment: Why is that 200 MB space unallocated? Maybe that's the issue... Windows doesn't mount it because the partition is not at the beginning of the disk.

Comment: you don’t need a computer that has Linux. You can boot any modern computer from a Linux live CD/flash drive

Answer (score 0):

If there is any manufacturer's testing software that can check the drive for errors, maybe SMART testing, try those first.

And you can create a bootable linux dvd/usb and boot your computer from it, here's some example instructions for Ubuntu, though Linux Mint & most Ubuntu-derived distros are nearly identical:

- Download the ISO - [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GettingUbuntu) or [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php)
- Make a dvd - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto
- Or make a usb - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

  - I'd use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), it used to work excellently, or [YUMI – Multiboot USB Creator](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

Then boot linux (run live / try before installing - no need to install at all) and attempt some Data Recovery - this [Ubuntu Community Wiki page on Data Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) covers about all the bases.

- Taking a look with `lsblk` or `parted -l` or `fdisk -l` or `blkid` should identify the target drive (soemthing like /dev/sdb or sdX).
- Then a mount could work, the GUI file manager should be able to do that, or if it has problems & needs to be read-only, this might do it:
  `mkdir /mountpoint && sudo mount -o ro /dev/sdX /mountpoint`
- Or if not, then continue with the "stronger" tools like `testdisk`/`photorec`, or a full drive image with `gddrescue` if the drive itself is having lots of read errors.